# VS2010 Express - Master Page template missing, and no Command Window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm running VS2010 Express with .NET 4.0 and trying to create a Master Page for a WPF Browser App. Problem is, there is no Master Page template.

I searched around a bit and found that  need to run "devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates" from the IDE Command window . . . . . which is also missing.

Is this a known restriction of the Express version, or is my installation missing something?
Will a full uninstall / reinstall fix this problem?

Has any one else experienced this?

Any help greatly appreciated - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run it from any cmd window, the visual studio command prompt just sets some extra path stuff. You'll need to be in the devenv directory for that to run.

The path variables all relate to paths of visual studio components.

It basically runs C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat

There's no guarantee that will work as a solution though. Express is pretty damn good, but they do disable stuff to justify the free price tag :)

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for the quick response. I can't find a devenv directory on my machine from either the VC# or VC directories, and no devenv.exe or even the vcvars32.bat. I'm suspecting my VS 2010 installation might not be what it should be. Looks like a full uninstall / reinstall might be on the cards.